# RDotNet (R.NET) issues in Azure Functions

Tags: r, azure, r.net

I have an Azure Function that executes R code by using `RDotNet` library (R.Net)
Everything works fine on my local environment, but when I deploy my code to [[image]azure](/questions/tagged/azure), the process to load specific libraries (`zoo`, `TTR`) never ends.

This is my code:

```
string rHome = @"D:\home\site\wwwroot\R\R-3.4.4";          
string rPath = Path.Combine(rHome, System.Environment.Is64BitProcess ? 
@"bin\x64" : @"bin\i386");                
            REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(rPath, rHome);  
            if (engine == null)
            {
                engine = REngine.GetInstance();
            }    

            engine.Evaluate(@"library(data.table)");               
            engine.Evaluate(@"library(RODBC)");               
            engine.Evaluate(@"library(nlstools)");                
            engine.Evaluate(@"library(minpack.lm)");              
            engine.Evaluate(@"library(zoo)");
            engine.Evaluate(@"library(TTR)");
```

The first 4 libraries are loaded without any problem, but when the program tries to load `zoo` library this process never ends and I cannot continue executing the rest of my code.

No error is displayed so the Azure Function is restarted after some minutes.
Same thing happens with library `TTR`

Any idea on what could be the cause of these symptoms?